# Does my app's name appear in Settings->iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

I have integrated iCloud into my app. Will the Settings app's iCloud page show my app's name now, as it would for Push Notifications?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @JoshCaswell i tried it i just make documents on but i did not get my name there

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iCloud *Documents & Data* then it will show your app name in under the iCloud section in Settings.app (iCloud–>Storage & Backup–>Manage Storage).

The only definitive way to know is to test it and see if it appears.

Comment: i am nit getting my app name just i making documents on